# How to obtain strain and stress values by editing abaqus input file?

Tags: structural-engineering, finite-element-method, abaqus

I am currently working on abaqus modeling, I am trying to find a quick way to get the strain and stress values shown in the output file.

What do I need to put in the .inp file? Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean « what do you have to put in the input file to get the stress and strain values shown in the output file »?

Comment: hi Solar Mike, yes you are right. that is what I meant

Comment: stress and strain field output reporting (to the output database file) is active by default, so the answer is "nothing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just guessing you might be seeking ascii human readable reporting, you can put in the inp file, (after your first `*STEP` line.)

```
   *EL PRINT,ELSET=setname
   E
   S
```

this will dump the data into your ".dat" file.  This is primarily useful if you want data for a small element set (like one particular element).  If you need the whole model data do yourself a favor and learn to directly read the output database (odb) file.