# How to get all forces and displacements values in abaqus and export it to excel?

Tags: finite-element-method, abaqus

I have made bridge model in Abaqus,
I also have done experimental study and I have the load-displacement data from my experiment,

I am now going to compare the results from Abaqus and the results from experiment

From this step, I want to compare the load-displacement curves between experiment and analysis in Abaqus.

how to get this information from abaqus to excel, please help me resolve this problem, I really appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: Your answer is in the answer to this question : get the values in the output file, see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/19089/10902

Comment: Solar Mike, currently I am having line number limit in dat file so I cannot all the data, I have edited the maximum line number limit into 1000 million, but everytime I open the dat file the same warning message said that max line number reached. So I am trying to find another way, since maybe my model is quite big, so maybe they cannot record all in dat file

Comment: Is it the production of the output file that has the data limit? If so, then run the model in separate steps or phases so you have 2 or 3 result files. If it is when you open in excel - then split the output into separate files : consider averaging the steps for example you could average each two steps to be one and that may still give you the info / results you need...

Comment: Thank you @SolarMike, I really appreciate that, I will try this solution..

Comment: excel has a limit of roughly one million rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I input the separated input files to solve the maximum line number limit in dat file